# DateTimeFormatter fails with DateTimeParseException

Tags: java-8

Parsing date string using `DateTimeFormatter` fails at blank space. Can someone point out what am I missing?

```
String dateStr = "10/10/2015 4:00:00 PM"
LocalDateTime.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US));

java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '10/10/2015 4:00:00 PM' could not be parsed at index 11
```

Comment: change `hh:mm:ss` to `h:mm:ss`

Comment: Good catch. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It failed because the format of the input string is not yet correct. If you want `hh:mm:ss`, you need to have your input as `04:00:00` - with the hour as `04` to match `hh`.